# MS Access SQL - SELECT IIF in a BoxList

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a form with a BoxList that will contain some informations as shown here :

[image]

This informations are selected through the following SQL query :

```
SELECT 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_id, 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_nom, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_prenom, 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_date_fin_emploi_actuel, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_effectif_contractualise
FROM 
   T_EMPLOI 
INNER JOIN (T_SALARIE INNER JOIN T_SALARIE_EMPLOI ON T_SALARIE.SALARIE_NNI = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni) ON T_EMPLOI.EMPLOI_identifiant = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant WHERE (((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_statut_id)=2) And ((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant)=Forms!F_Vue_Emploi.Form!EMPLOI_identifiant));
```

What I want now is to change 0 into 'Non' and 1 into 'Oui' in the 4th column (Effectif contractualise).
[image]

So I tried the `Select Case When`, but going through the other publications in Stack, I realized that it doesn't work in Access and That I should be using the 'IIF' Function.

So I tried the following query :

```
SELECT 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_id, 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_nom, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_prenom, 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_date_fin_emploi_actuel, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_effectif_contractualise,
IIF(T_SALARIE.SALARIE_effectif_contractualise = 1, 'Oui', 'Non') as Effectif Contractualisé
FROM 
   T_EMPLOI 
INNER JOIN (T_SALARIE INNER JOIN T_SALARIE_EMPLOI ON T_SALARIE.SALARIE_NNI = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni) ON T_EMPLOI.EMPLOI_identifiant = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant WHERE (((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_statut_id)=2) And ((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant)=Forms!F_Vue_Emploi.Form!EMPLOI_identifiant));
```

The error occurs When the line `IIF(T_SALARIE.SALARIE_effectif_contractualise = 1, 'Oui', 'Non') as Effectif Contractualisé` showing that there is an issue with the query, either the punctuation is incorrect or something has been misspelled.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: *but it's not working* -- please edit your question and specify the actual problem. Error message? Wrong result? (then provide sample data, actual and expected result)

Comment: Try `as [Effectif Contractualisé]`. Names with spaces must be wrapped in `[ ]` brackets.

Comment: Well I tried it and the error is gone but I don't get the result I want nothing changed the 0 stayed 0 and didn't change to 'Non'. Same thing for 1

Comment: You have the same field in your query above the IIF - make sure you're using the correct one.

Comment: It is actually a numeric field. And still, I tried your proposition and it didn't work.

Comment: Actually yes this is what I'm doing in the query I'm calling the field and after that I'm making changes in it. Doesn't work like that ?

Comment: You don't need this field `T_SALARIE.SALARIE_effectif_contractualise,` - the IIF below it is enough unless you want the 0 and 1 as well.

Comment: Is "BoxList" a combobox or a listbox? What are ColumnCount and ColumnWidths properties set to?